# ObjectInputStream does not work with Sockets

Tags: java, sockets, input, stream

a few days ago, I started to code a little multiplayer game, in wich I use ObjectInputStreams and ObjectOutputStreams in order to exchange data with a server. But for some reason, the server does not recieve anything. So I searched for some help, but everything I found was, that I have to flush the ObjectOutputStream. Of course I did this, but it is not the solution for my problem. So I wrote a tiny test application, that does the same as my game. But there is still the same problem: The InputStream does not recieve anything. So here's my code for the test app:

Server application:

```
    try {
        ServerSocket srvr = new ServerSocket(12975);

        Socket client = srvr.accept();

        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        out.flush();

        System.out.println("server ready!");

        String line = "";
        while(!line.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")){
            while(in.available() <= 0){}
            line = in.readObject().toString();
            System.out.println(">>> recieved: " + line);
        }

        client.close();
        srvr.close();
        System.exit(0);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And here's the client application:

```
    try {
        Socket client = new Socket("localhost", 12975);

        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        out.flush();
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());

        System.out.println("client ready!");
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String line = "";
        while(!line.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")){
            System.out.print("> ");
            line = input.readLine();
            out.writeObject(line);
            out.flush();
        }

        client.close();
        System.exit(0);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
```

I tried to do this to both sides: Server->Client and Client->Server, but both Sockets did not recieve anything. Any research failed, because everyone seems to forget the flush() after constructing the OutputStream, but then it works.
So I hope, anyone knows this problem and is able to help me.

P.S: I am not from England nor from America, so sorry, if my English contains mistakes! :D

Comment: You have told us what is the problem? Can you post us any stacktrace or anything to help

Comment: A `Reader` is made to read text, not binary. Don't use that

Comment: What do you think `while (in.available() <= 0) {}` is suppose to do on server side? Have you tried removing it? Hint: `in.readObject()` will wait until there will be data to read, or connection will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this , this is working.

```
while(!line.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")){
    while(in.available() <= 0){
        line = in.readObject().toString();
        System.out.println(">>> recieved: " + line);
    }
}
```

You have mistaken with your second **`while`** loop parenthesis in **server code**.

Comment: Well, thanks, it worked, but I do not understand it. Why can the stream recieve something, while there are zero or less than zero bytes available???
I thought there should be more than zero bytes available, until the stream can recieve something?!

Comment: I don't know game's context , so how can i answer?, please create new question with describing your game's context.

Comment: @user3368075 show me that where your stream is receiving "something" while there are zero or less than zero bytes are available.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22114510/further-problems-with-objectinputstreams-with-sockets?noredirect=1)

Here's a new thread with the main problem...

Comment: The available() test and loop should be *removed.* It is essentially nonsense to read if available() <= 0. It happens to work here because ObjectInputStream.available() must be returning zero, but it's still nonsense code.